# Complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

How to calculate the limit of the complex sequence: $z_{1}=1$ and $z_{n+1}=z_{n}(1-\frac{1+i}{n})$. I try to calculate and I noticed that it is a geometric sequence. So may I write $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} z_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1-\frac{1+i}{n})^n$ ? My answer is $e^{-1-i}$. Is it correct?

Comment: This is not a geometric sequence, since the multiplicative coefficient between $z_n$ and $z_{n+1}$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Okey.. you are right :/ so my limit is incorrect?

Comment: note that for any complex $a \ne 0$ and $n$ large enough so for example $2|a| <n$ we have that $\log (1-a/n)=-a/n +O(|a|^2/n^2)$ hence $|\sum_{n \ge n_0} \log (1-a/n)| = \infty$ so the product diverges (as product theory goes though it may have  a limit of course) - depending on the real part of $a$ it can go to zero, to $\infty$ or oscillate - here since $\Re a =1$ it will go to zero since $\Re \sum_{n \ge n_0} \log (1-a/n) \to -\infty$ hence $|z_n| \to 0$

Comment: You can prove inductively that $$z_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( 1-\frac{1+i}{k}\right)$$ If you know the $\Gamma$ function, this product can be expressed in a closed way.

Comment: Omg It is so complicated

Comment: in general when dealing with infinite products, the best way is to use logarithms as any product $\Pi b_n$ that is not obviously divergent (that includes of course the limit zero, but that will still be obvious if $b_n \not \to 1$) must have $b_n  \to 1$ so can be written as $1+a_n, a_n \to 0$ and then one can use the taylor series of the logarithm and classical results about series